# Looking for low-priced SharePoint 2010 or 2013 host

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, hosting

I host a handful of public websites, using SharePoint Foundation 2010. My current hosting service is not reliable, am actively searching for a new company. I don't want to manage my own server, and I can't afford $100s of dollars a month. Office 365 has some plusses, but can only make one public Site Collection. Any recommendations for a web site host with SharePoint Foundation for under $200 a year?

Answer (score 1):

Apps4rent.com is reliable hosting company so far, i have my foundation site with them.
http://www.apps4rent.com/hosted-sharepoint-2013-plans.html

Also check the plexhosted.com they have cheap rates then app4rent

http://plexhosted.com/services/hosted-sharepoint-2013/hosted-sharepoint-foundation-2013.html

Comment: Are they based in the U.S.?
Is there a phone number you can call for tech support, not just a double-secret help desk submission process that can't send you an email that they replied?
Do they understand SharePoint better than you?

Comment: I'm not like bitter or anything.

Comment: they have US phone number and 24/7, also they have their online chat. with apps4rent i had issue with my site collection and i chat with them and they resolved the issue. they are better than me...its depend on me how much knowidge i have....I think you best option talk to them and check the reviews on internet.